# How do I properly format a JSON payload in PHP without invalid whitespace for a REST API post call?

Tags: php

Need to remove whitespaces/invalid spaces in json string to pass as payload in rest api post call.

Currently it displaying:-

```
{ "channel":{"id" : 6},"entryType" : {"id" : 1},"contentType": {"id": 2},"text":"
tttttt
" }
```

Expecting:-

```
{ "channel":{"id" : 6}, "entryType" : {"id" : 1}, "text" : "Test1" }
```

Assigning the value to the "text" key is dynamic.

Comment: If you only need to remove whitespace from "text" field, you can use `trim($text," ")` to remove leading and trailing whitespaces before assigning it to  the json object. If you only need to remove leading whitespaces, u can use `ltrim()` and for trailing, you can use `rtrim()`

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on trimming whitespace in PHP. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp#:~:text=The%20trim()%20function%20removes,right%20side%20of%20a%20string

Comment: There's all sorts of odd whitespace in your examples. How are you generating this? Presumably not by using `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove whitespaces at the beginning or end of the text field, you can use trim:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
$text = ' this is a test ';
$text = trim($text);
// $test ---> 'this is a test'
```

But, if the objective were remove all whitespaces, I would use str_replace:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$text = $text = ' this is a test ';
$text = str_replace(' ', '', $text);
// $test ---> 'thisisatest'
```

This will eliminate all spaces, even between of the text, so if you want pass complete sentences or paragraphs, trim will be a better option.